# How to view GoogleDrive changes in StackDriver

Tags: google-workspace, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've just started using StackDriver and I'm failing to get GoogleDrive logs (or any GSuite logs for that matter).

From the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/audit-logging) I understand that I need to read the Audit Logs in SD, but I'm not sure how to connect them to SD.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible to gather any logs from Google Drive by StackDriver since it's a Gsuite product and it's not supported.**

Stackdriver will work only with Google Cloud Platform / AWS or standalone machines and it requires [installation of monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) on them. In case of GCP VM's it's preinstalled by default.

You can read in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/services) which services are supported by StackDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I think a less granular approach is to use the GSuite Exporter (link below) to export user activity **events** from the Admin SDK Reports API into StackDriver. You'll need to grant extra IAM roles for the service account to have visibility, but it is possible.

**GSuite-Exporter**: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/tools/gsuite-exporter